# Using multiple Views for the same page without code replication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 I am trying to show a `View` tailored to the environment that the end user is accessing it in. I am achieving this by accessing the `user agent` string and return the relevant `View`.

Controller:

```
string userAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
if (userAgent.Contains("ipad"))
{
   viewPath = "~/Views/Home/Index.Ipad.cshtml";
}
else if (userAgent.Contains("android"))
{
   viewPath = "~/Views/Home/Index.Android.cshtml";
}
else
{
   viewPath = "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml";
}
```

The Android and iPad `Views` will not have major differences, meerly small adjustments to account for rendering differences. The main `Index.cshtml` will contain more data that the desktop screen will allow for.

This will lead to a large amount of code replication. One change will need to be replicated across three `Views`. Is there an easier / better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of partial views to handle common areas of content would help - as would varying within the views themselves would help mitigate this.

If possible the rendering differences should be handled in CSS, to reduce the need for any customisation, however!